# How to draw a heat map of a computational intensive function in R

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I need to draw a heat map of a function f. The standard way to do that is to create a data frame of the (x, y) values, and to compute f(x, y). This method is however very computational intensive, because it requires to compute f for every pixel. It would require weeks for me. Is there any package that could use decide which points to compute and to approximate my function on the whole plot?

I thought of using things like gaussian processes for estimating the function, given the previously computed points, and decide which area has the highest uncertainty and could benefit from an additional computation in it.

My function is smooth except on a few points. I expect the algorithm to explore the neighborhoods of this points to limit the uncertainty of the final approximation.

Comment: I don't see how clustering methods would be applied to decide which points to compute - my guess is that your best bet is first to compute your function on a relatively sparse (x,y) grid, and then interpolate on a finer grid to obtain z values at a better resolution.

Comment: I am not really sure about which algorithm could work well, the goal is to find which interpolated points are the more uncertain. Interpolate on a sparse grid is not efficient enough, because my function is quite flat on the majority of the plot.

Comment: If your function isn't "smooth" or , worse, is chaotic (see "fractals"), then there's no way to predict or smooth it.  You might want to investigate multicore parallel processing techniques.

Comment: My function is smooth enough (at least uniformly continuous) on the whole plot, except maybe on a finite number of points. Multicore could be a trick for faster computations (2-4x for me), but it doesn't change the magnitude of the calculations.